# Returning objects in JavaScript in different ways, one works the other doesn't

Tags: javascript, object

Below code works

```js
return {
  getinput:function(){
    return{
      type:document.querySelector(domStrings.inputType).value,
      description:document.querySelector(domStrings.inputDescription).value,
      value:document.querySelector(domStrings.inputValue).value
    };
  }
}
```

and below code doesn't

```js
var klop={
  type:document.querySelector(domStrings.inputType).value,
  description:document.querySelector(domStrings.inputDescription).value,
  value:document.querySelector(domStrings.inputValue).value
};

return {
  getinput:function(){
    return klop;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please define _"doesn't work"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working version:

```
return {
  getinput:function(){
    return{
      type:document.querySelector(domStrings.inputType).value,
      description:document.querySelector(domStrings.inputDescription).value,
      value:document.querySelector(domStrings.inputValue).value
    };
  }
}
```

Every time you call the `getinput()` function, it gets all the values and creates a new object containing them, so you get the current values of the inputs.

Non-working version:

```
var klop={
  type:document.querySelector(domStrings.inputType).value,
  description:document.querySelector(domStrings.inputDescription).value,
  value:document.querySelector(domStrings.inputValue).value
};

return {
  getinput:function(){
    return klop;
  }
}
```

This gets the values of the inputs just once, when you create the object with the function that this is part of. Every time you call `getinput()` it returns the same `klop` object, it doesn't get the current values of the inputs.

Comment: hi Barmar thank you for helping me out, so your answer in other words - when I call getinput.type, instead of returning the actual value from domString(from my html input field) it just returns 'document.querySelector(domStrings.inputType).value'  in the non working version? Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: The non-working version is saving a snapshot of the values when you first called the constructor.